# Laravel auth not displaying session message

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to authenticate a user type in laravel 5.2. The route is as below :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/user/department/login', ['as' => 'department_login', 'uses' => 'DepartmentUserAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('/user/department/login','DepartmentUserAuth\AuthController@deptLoginPost');

});
```

And the `AuthController.php` is

```
public function deptLoginPost(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'      => 'required',
        'password'      => 'required',
    ]);
    if (auth()->guard('department_user')->attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')]))
    {
        $user = auth()->guard('department_user')->user();
        dd($user);
    }else{
       return redirect('/user/department/login')->with('message', 'Invalid credentials');
    }
}
```

And the `login.blade.php` is :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
               {!! Session::get('message') !!}
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
@endif

{{ dump(session()->all()) }}
```

But the `Session::has('message')` is empty, and the `dump` shows as below :

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "BvQ630KrUl78Ngb8d3cst6pAIqenra3ohbYbLzAP"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▼
    "url" => "http://localhost:8080/material/public/user/department/login"
  ]
  "flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
]
```

How can I display all error messages ( as in default auth controller ) in my `login.blade.php` ?

Comment: paste your `config/auth.php` code

Comment: You can add a message like this. `$request->request->add(['message' => "Your custome Message"]);` without puting into session. Redirect back withInput()

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the message directly on the request's message:

`$request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid credentials');`

example:

```
if (auth()->guard('department_user')->attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')]))
{
    $user = auth()->guard('department_user')->user();
    dd($user);
}else{
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid credentials');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

If still doesn't help, look into your routes and see if your middleware is assigned properly.

```
// either as a string
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web']...
// or as a array element
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']]...
```

Comment: Why does this change make a difference regarding the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This should be working, as far as I can tell (in fact, I just tried this in a fresh Laravel 5.2 installation and it worked as expected). My only guess is, the `with` method doesn't write the message "permanently" in the session, but in the flash data (only available for the next request cycle). If, for some reason, you are getting a redirection response, that response will consume the flash data, and by the time you reach the login form again, the message is no longer in the session.

So, are you doing any redirection other than the one in the `AuthController`? Maybe in a middleware?

Some things you could try:

- Add some middleware that logs every request ([see, how to log every response in Laravel 5.2 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249995/how-to-log-every-response-in-laravel-5-2-framework)) so you can trace if there are additional redirects.
- Add `session()->reflash();` to a middleware that runs with every request. (If this work this should prove my point that the flash data is being consumed in an intermediate request).
- Replace

  ```
  return redirect('/user/department/login')
      ->with('message', 'Invalid credentials');
  ```

  with

  ```
  return redirect()
      ->back()->with('message', 'Invalid credentials');
  ```
- Replace (only temporarily, to test you can write and read from the session store)

  ```
  return redirect('/user/department/login')
      ->with('message', 'Invalid credentials');
  ```

  with

  ```
   session(['message' => 'Invalid credentials']);
   return redirect('/user/department/login');
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, routes in `routes.php` file already use the `web` middleware by default so there's no need to wrap it again.

That `Route::auth()` is using the default Laravel auth routes, maybe you have a conflict with them and your  department login ones, so try removing that line.

For last, I recommend to use `session()->flash('message', 'Invalid credentials');` instead of `->with()`

Answer (score 1):

Also, using the `Session` facade:

```
//display error message
Session::flash('message', 'Invalid credentials')

//color the output
Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger')
```

Or, with [laracasts/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash), you could:

```
//AuthController
flash('Invalid credentials')->error();

//login.blade.php
@include('flash::message')
```